# Parse date and use setdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

2015-12-14 this is my date format, do I have to parse this to date format if I want to use setdate?

I want to attach to a click event where user can go to previous and next date.

Comment: yes u have to parse into date format like `var dt= new Date("2015-12-12")` after that u can use `setDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript date setDate() method sets the day of the month for a specified date according to local time.

Expected values are 1-31, but other values are allowed:

- 0 will result in the last day of the previous month
- -1 will result    in the day before the last day of the previous month

If the month has 31 days:

- 32 will result in the first day of the next month

If the month has 30 days:

- 32 will result in the second day of the next month

```js
var dt = new Date("2015-12-14");
dt.setDate(33);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: so I don't have to handle the months? just add the days are ok? says the user want to go to next day, I just grab 14 and +1? that's it?

Comment: Yes. If you need to change the month of the date then use setMonth() method. setDate() method is used to change the day of the date.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to store this into `date object` if you want to use `setDate` method because only `date object` would have this method an `ordinary object` will not have that method.

```
var date=new Date("2015-12-14");
date.setDate(15);
```

Comment: is this easy? what if it's 31 Jan, I do +1, will it return me the correct month and date?

Comment: `setDate` only set the current date to what you pass in this.

Comment: Add if you add days or months it will return you correct date.

Comment: add days or month? how to actually accurately do yesterday or tomorrow then?